# Recording multiple users at the same time

Tags: servlets

My requirement is to record users voice and save it on the server (multiple users simultaneously). Here is my code:

```
in = (InputStream) request.getInputStream();                         
fos = new FileOutputStream(f1);
int read = 0;
while ((read = in.read()) != -1) {
    fos.write(read);
}
fos.close();
in.close();
```

I am getting the following exception when trying to record voices for multiple users at a time, I do not get this exception with a single user:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.readByte(InputBuffer.java:315)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:105)
    at CommonPackage.Upload.processRequest(Upload.java:78)
    at CommonPackage.Upload.doPost(Upload.java:115)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1675)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Thanks

Comment: Post the error message you get. Show stack-trace.

Comment: what is the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Do not close InputStream object.

Thumb rule : If you have not opened an connection or stream, do not close it.

Comment out in.close()